# How do I append a DO droplet to a project with terraform/tofu?

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean, opentofu

I want to create a new droplet, then *add* it to an existing project, which has other existing droplets in it already.

I can see how to create a new project and put the droplet in that - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/project

I can see how to put the droplet in an existing project - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/project_resources

But both of these options just sets the `resources` value to be a list of the single droplet, which is going to wipe out anything else that's already there, surely?

How do I *append* a new droplet to an existing project? Essentially what I want is something like

```
resources = resources.append(digitalocean_droplet.artbio_se.urn)
```

Comment: Usually you would just add another element to the list if it's only adding. You can add more than one resource to the `resources` argument, as it's a list.

Comment: Sure, but my terraform setup doesn't know what's there currently - how do I get the new list?

Comment: So you have created things manually, right? And now you want to move it under IaC?

Comment: There is a pre-existing project, where some stuff has been manually deployed, yes, and I want IaC configuration for a new deployment to add a new droplet and put it under that project. Droplet creation is all fine - it's only setting the project that is problematic.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the project supports imports, otherwise I would tell you to import the resource into state.

Comment: So basically, if I talk in http terms for simplicity, I can do a POST or a PUT, but not a PATCH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please read about "state" concept in the terraform:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state

If you want to add something already existing, you need to:

- create terraform configuration for that (create *.tf file with resource description);
- import your existing infrastructure to the terraform state by using [terraform import](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import) command;

But this will work only if your terraform provider support of existing infrastructure.

For example `digitalocean_project` support import, how described in their [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/project):

```
Projects can be imported using the id returned from DigitalOcean, e.g.
terraform import digitalocean_project.myproject 245bcfd0-7f31-4ce6-a2bc-475a116cca97
```

Also `digitalocean_droplet` support import, like:

```
terraform import digitalocean_droplet.mydroplet 100823
```

And digitalocean have a resource `digitalocean_project_resources` which allow you to assign resources to a already existing DigitalOcean Project.

And if you already have project and want to add existings droplets and create a new one you need:

- create configuration like described [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/project_resources) and describe all existing droplets in the configuration;
- import all existing droplets as I wrote previously;
- run `terraform plan` and make sure that no new droplets will be created, that means your import worked correctly;
- add a new droplet to this configuration and run `terraform plan` and you will see that terraform wants create only the new droplet;